# Ubuntu 16.04 print PDF issue

Tags: printing, pdf, evince

I'm trying to print **PDF** document on **Ubuntu 16.04** via Epson **L310 printer**. I open the PDF document with evince and select `"file->print"`, and I can print it successfully. But when I try to print it via command line command **'lp'** or **'lpr'**, the **PDF** document printed something is missing, and can't print successfully. So why this happens? What's the difference between print **PDF** document via evince reader `"file->print"` and directly via command **'lp'** or **'lpr'** ?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe, `lp` is using  the default print options (if you invoke the command as is, without dabbling with `lpoptions/lpàdmin`), and in evince you are selecting them.

Comment: Hello @S.Ith, so what options should I set? I found that if the PDF document contains not embedded fonts, then can't been printed correctly by `lp test.pdf`. So how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56274/printing-pdf-with-not-embedded-truetype-font-cups-lpr#122556)?. It seems that you might have to add the fonts to the printer renderer.

Comment: Hi @S.Ith, I've read the post, but I still don't know how to do it, do you have any ideas? Thanks.